# Unable to turn off strict host checking when rsync'ing between two servers using agent forwarding

Tags: ssh, rsync

I got this command:

```
ssh -A admin@example.org rsync -avz /etc/apache2/ssl admin@172.30.0.139:/etc/apache2
```

It throws an error:

```
Host key verification failed
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

So I modified the command to this:

```
ssh -A -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" admin@exmaple.org rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /etc/apache2/ssl admin@172.30.0.139:/etc/apache2
```

I still get the same error, however.

**UPDATE**
If I first manually ssh into the example.org machine using agent forwarding and then ssh into 172.30.0.139 from example.org and then exit and then run the rsync command, everything works. I would of course like to avoid having to jump through this extra hoop.

Comment: If i'm trying to automate rsync, I typically add a ssh-keyscan first.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not familiar with that command. Did a quick search and it looks like I would run that on the 172.30.0.139 machine using the ip address of my local machine? So ssh-keyscan -H 111.111.111.111 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts. Is that right?

Comment: You can run it against the hostname, but otherwise, yep that looks right.  In your case, you might need to run it on both the local machine, and remote host.

Comment: You may be running into trouble because the remote command (`rsync -avz ...`) goes through shell parsing -- including quote removal -- twice, once on the local system and then again on the remote system. The double-quotes in `... -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" ...` get applied and removed on the local system, but you need them to apply on the remote system. Try with two layers of quotes, like `... -e '"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"' ...`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465980/how-to-keep-parameter-with-spaces-when-running-remote-script-file-with-ssh).

Comment: Looks like this was the issue. Thanks!